# Timer Interval Increases when CPU utilization and memory increases

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, cpu

I have a Timer in my code for some 'x' seconds. The code has multiple threads and there are multiple timers. Now I notice that, my application goes to a hang state after running for some time and from the logs I notice that the timer interval varies. It has increased. How is this possible and can anyone provide a solution for this? Is there any alternative for timer in c#

```
      _timernew = new System.Timers.Timer(10000)
            {
                AutoReset = false
            };
            _timernew .Elapsed += (sender, e) => { DoSomething };
            _timernew .Enabled = true;
```

Comment: please add some source code to investigate

Comment: We can not help you without any source code or a example which recreates the problem.

Comment: Imagine, you have an important job to do every 5 seconds which will take 1 second. Easy to manage. Now you have to handle 6 of this important jobs -> easy to handle in time?

Comment: There is at least 5 timer classes in C#. Which one do you use?

Comment: @vasily.sib I am using System.Timers.Timer

Comment: @HienNguyen  Code for timer in edits

Comment: @Lloyd Code for timer in edits

Comment: You shouldn't expect timers be accurate because there are lot of factors related to preemptive multitasking, but it's unclear from you post how your timer interval varies are what is meant by "application goes to a hang state".

Comment: The Timer only promises a delay of _at least_ interval. When that has passed, it will just have to wait its turn. Windows is not a RT OS.

Comment: Your question is still too short on details. Zoom out and tell us what the timer is for.

Comment: From what you described it rather looks like overall application performance degradation which can be related to many things like memory leaks, GC pressure, thread pool pressure, etc. I'd suggest to monitor at list the basic metrics of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Timers are not precise.  The interval is the minimum delay before the event is fired, but you are not guaranteed your timer event will get executed exactly when the interval elapses.

When the interval elapses, the timer queues your even handler to the thread pool.  Therefore, the event handler will get executed when there is an available thread in the threadpool to take the handler, and then an available CPU core to actually execute it.

In other words, the more busy the computer is, the more likely delays will happen.

If you need a closer to real-time execution, you must use a dedicated thread and set its priority to high:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(MyThreadMethod);
myThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
myThread.Start();
```

Now, however, in your MyThreadMethod, you need to implement a sophisticated mechanism that monitors how much time has elapsed and decide whether you must execute your actual code or not.

You should not just loop and  check the time, because that will occupy a single core at 100%.  Perhaps you can use the dreaded `Thread.Sleep` with a smaller interval and check if time has passed.  You must use a smaller interval than the one you need at a magnitude of at least 10.  `Thread.Sleep` is not precise, too.